# Python multiple inheritance does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I get an error `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label_text'` in line `QLineEdit.__init__(self)` which doesn't make sense to me. I create `Input` object by passing one keyword argument `label_text` as `Input(label_text="Example label")`. I assume an error happens because of how constructors of base classes are called, though I am not sure what's exactly wrong.

```
from enum import IntEnum, auto
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFocusEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QTextEdit

class InputType(IntEnum):
    Text = auto()
    Password = auto()

class InputBase:
    def __init__(self, label_text: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.label_text = label_text
        self.label = QLabel(label_text)
        self.label.setObjectName('input-label')
        self.setPlaceholderText('')

    def focusInEvent(self, event: QFocusEvent) -> None:
        if self.is_empty():
            self.setPlaceholderText("")
            self.label.setText(self.label_text)

        super().focusInEvent(event)
    
    def focusOutEvent(self, event: QFocusEvent) -> None:
        if self.is_empty():
            self.setPlaceholderText(self.label_text)
            self.label.setText(" ")

        super().focusOutEvent(event)
    
    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Input(QLineEdit, InputBase):
    def __init__(self, label_text: str, type: InputType = InputType.Text) -> None:
        QLineEdit.__init__(self)
        InputBase.__init__(self, label_text)

        if type == InputType.Password:
            self.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        return self.text() == ""

class TextArea(QTextEdit, InputBase):
    def __init__(self, label_text: str) -> None:
        QLineEdit.__init__(self)
        InputBase.__init__(self, label_text)

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        return self.toPlainText() == ""
```

Comment: The example you provided is giving another error than the one described on the post: `TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QLineEdit' object but received a 'TextArea'`. It means that you typed the wrong constructor in `TextArea`. It should be a QTextEdit, not a QLineEdit. **About the error from the post:** the script works without errors (note: I'm using PySide2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (MRO), which you are not respecting in calling the `__init__` of the super classes, and is related to the [Linkov substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which should respect the positional arguments in the MRO.

Shortly put, since the `__init__` of `InputBase` requires a positional argument, and the inheritance is put *after* the `QLineEdit` base class, the `__init__` of `QLineEdit` should have that positional argument too.

A simple solution would be to call the super class methods in the correct order (the *opposite* of the MRO), but that would not be valid for two reasons:

1. `InputBase` relies `setPlaceholderText()`, which is an attribute that is part of QLineEdit;
2. based on your code, `InputBase` should *override* the Qt functions, but your MRO tries to do the opposite;

So, the real solution is to use the correct inheritance order: first `InputBase`, *then* `QLineEdit`.

Consider that it's usually better to avoid mixing `super()` with explicit calls (especially if they have different positional arguments), unless you really know what you're doing. By doing the above, that would also be unnecessary, so you can just call `super()` in the init too.

```py
class Input(InputBase, QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, label_text: str, type: InputType = InputType.Text) -> None:
        super().__init__(label_text)
```

Note that you should do the same for `TextArea` too, which is also wrong right now, since its `__init__` calls QLineEdit instead of QTextEdit.